# How to detect whether personal wifi hotspot or recording is undergoing on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Since the red/blue glowing banner will block quite a lot of the interface. http://d.pr/SfgW

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This gives you the height of the status bar:

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
```

With Personal Hotspot enabled, it returns 40, and returns 20 otherwise.

Comment: Brilliant.  Simple answer to a simple question.

Comment: Is it just me? This returns an odd value when in landscape - or at least a strange value in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: for me 480. It looks like the status bar goes back to being just single height so ignoring this for now.

Comment: This is the simplest answer until iPhone X released...... Is any other solution for now?

Answer (score 4):

The statusbar height is 40 even when you have an active call by pressing the home button durring a phone call, therefore you can not determine whether or not the personal hotspot is on.

Answer (score 2):

you can get text message if any device is connect to hotspot.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILabel *subviews12 = [[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"doubleHeightLabel"];
```